# Question concerning a prepositional phrase

Tags: prepositions, dative-alternation

In the prepositional phrase : **"Who did you give your number to?"** Is the TO at the end of the sentence absolutely necessary?

Comment: "This is the sort of English up with which I will not put." -- Sir Ernest Gowers on why it's not so bad to put prepositions at the end of a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb *give* participates in something called the Dative Alternation:

> I gave the book **to him**.
>   I gave **him** the book.

Both of these sentences can be used with the same meaning.  Levin gives the following examples of verbs that participate in the Dative Alternation:

- *give*-type verbs: *give, hand, lend, loan, rent, sell,* . . .
- *send*-type verbs: *send, mail, ship,* . . .
- *throw*-type verbs: *fling, flip, kick, lob, slap, shoot, throw, toss,* . . .

But the example I've given above is very simple.  If we make things more cognitively complex by making the example interrogative, then we find a strong preference for the version that is explicitly marked by a preposition.  Why?

In [*Cognitive complexity and increased grammatical explicitness in English*](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/cogl.1996.7.issue-2/cogl.1996.7.2.149/cogl.1996.7.2.149.xml), Günter Rohdenburg outlines his Complexity Principle, "explicitly marked phrases are preferred over zero-marked counterparts in cognitively complex environments".  Following this principle, it seems many speakers have a strong preference for including *to* in the interrogative version:

> Who did John give the book?
>   Who did John give the book **to**?

I personally find both versions grammatical, but I think you'll find that people usually choose to include this preposition in real life examples.

Answer (score 3):

The preposition *is* required to link **who** to the verb. If you omit it, it would be like omitting it from this sentence

> I gave my number **to** Joe (correct).
>
> I gave my number Joe (incorrect)

Note that it is permissible to omit the **to** for *this* type sentence by inverting the order of the direct object (number) and the [indirect object](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/indirectobject.htm) (Joe):

> I gave Joe my number (correct).

It is not, however, possible to omit the preposition from your sentence:

> Who did you give your number **to**?

Strictly speaking, **to** requires an accusative **whom**, but in spoken english most people say **who** in a sentence like this.

Answer (score 2):

In American English, these two are colloquial:

> Who did you give your number to?
>
> Who did you give your number?

and this is formal:

> To whom did you give your number?